# Make view of a page in laravel 5.1 using routes

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, redirect

I am trying to get a view page without passing extra parameters in url

routes.php

```
Route::controller('site','SiteController');
```

menu.php

```
<li><a href="{{url::to('/')}}">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{{url::to('site/about')}}">About</a></li>
<li><a href="{{url::to('site/contact')}}">Contact</a></li>
```

SiteController.php

```
public function index(){

return view('welcome');
}
public function getAbout(){

return view('about');
}
```

When I am trying to access my about page the URL is coming like `http://localhost/fitness/public/site/about` but here how can I modify my code to get URL like `http://localhost/fitness/public/about`?
It is happening for all other pages. I do not want to write get and post method in routes page. My routes page should remains with same code.I do not want site to come in `URL`.

Will this be possible ?? Can anybody help me out ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you have seperate route to handle `"/"` url?

Comment: first of all, have you tried `Route::controller('/','SiteController');` instead of `Route::controller('site','SiteController');` this way it should give result like `http://localhost/fitness/public/about` without the `site` part. unless you had another controller to handle `/` url.

Comment: Thank you @Tezla it worked...